# cart data not update in shopify using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-template

I have a Problem in Shopify.

I want update cart quantity on button click using ajax but it will give error like

> {"status":404,"message":"Cart Error","description":"Cannot find variant"}

Here is my ajax code,

```
 $('.adjust-plus').click(function(){
    var qty = $(this).parent('.button-wrapper').siblings('.input-wrapper').children('.quantity').val();
    var varient = $(this).parent('.button-wrapper').siblings('.input-wrapper').children('.quantity').attr('data-id');

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      url: '/cart/update.js',
      data: { updates: { varient : qty } },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() { location.href = '/cart'; }
   });
 });
```

currently in both variable value come so no any error in value.

> but when id add code like:

```
$('.adjust-plus').click(function(){
    var qty = $(this).parent('.button-wrapper').siblings('.input-wrapper').children('.quantity').val();
    var varient = $(this).parent('.button-wrapper').siblings('.input-wrapper').children('.quantity').attr('data-id');

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      url: '/cart/update.js',
      data: { updates: { 15082896588867 : 2 } },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() { location.href = '/cart'; }
   });
 });
```

then cart updated successfully.

Comment: Doesn't make sense sending a post to a js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, remove `async: false` as it's very bad practice and not needed here as you're using the `success` callback properly.

The issue itself is because you cannot use variables as the keys of an object with the syntax you're using. To get around this you can use bracket notation, like this:

```
$('.adjust-plus').click(function() {
  var $quantity = $(this).parent('.button-wrapper').siblings('.input-wrapper').children('.quantity');
  var qty = $quantity.val();
  var varient = $quantity.data('id');

  var data = { updates: {} };
  data.updates[varient] = qty;

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/update.js',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { 
      location.href = '/cart'; 
    }
  });
});
```